# Speed performance for recursion and iteration – Why do they both run at the same speed for different "small" numbers?

Tags: c#, performance

I'm trying to optimize code that I have. In order to do that, I wrote this code to see the effect of recursion vs. iteration. The code "counts" to 10-to-the-n'th power.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    recurse(4);
    //iterate(4);
    sw.Stop();
    Text = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
}

void recurse(int i)
{
    if (i < 1) return;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) recurse(i - 1);
}

void iterate(int i)
{
    i = (int)System.Math.Pow(10, i);
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) ;
}
```

I'm getting this unexpected result: when n is 1 through 4 the speed is around 0.5 ms for both recursion and iteration. -Instead of 4 being 1000 times slower than 1 which is what I expected. Only for greater numbers does it start to have a more intuitive speed, the iteration also being faster than the recursion.

Why the same speed for 10 times as for 10,000 times?

Comment: Iterate is running a tight loop and recurse is executing a call in a loop. That doesn't feel like a fair comparison.

Comment: think about it. how many iterations does the two methods do? They have completely diffrent time complexities... This question makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: @rene My question is not why recursion is slower. My question is why the same speed for 10 times as for 10,000 times.

Comment: @vidstige My question is not why recursion is slower. My question is why the same speed for 10 times as for 10,000 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you do correct the code to calculate the same thing in both cases, do not test things like that in one run. You're not going to get a proper result unless the test itself takes at least a second. Run it one million times and then divide the total time. When you're testing something that's going to take only a millisecond or two, you should make sure the test takes long enough to ignore the differences of cold cache, times of .Start() and .Stop() calls, small GC delay in the meantime, etc. Also make sure the actual work takes more time than empty counting loop (that is `for(many times) recurse(x)` has high enough `x` that the `for` itself is not relevant)

Your result of 0.5ms in a single run is more or less meaningless here. Also if it's a jitted language, I'd recommend calling the same function before testing, to ensure it's already compiled - otherwise it's going to add overhead.

TL;DR - overhead of other things happening around your function is higher than the time your function takes to execute.

Comment: Thanks.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ That's probably it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in your implementation of recurse.  Unless I am reading it incorrectly, recurse only runs 4 times and iterates 1 to 10 in each.  While iterate calculates 10^4 - 10,000 and then counts from 0 to 10,000.

So, you are not doing a fair comparison.

Revision:  If you are truly getting responses in the 0.5ms range, then you may have exceeded the accuracy of the functions involved.  This MS article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx has an example with nanosecond timing that you might find helpful.  It is a bit more work, but might provide insight.

Comment: a) No. recursion runs 10,000 as well. b) My question is not why recursion is slower. My question is why the same speed for 10 times as for 10,000 times.

Comment: I stand corrected, it does iterate the proper number of times.