# Difference between recursion and using for loop?

Tags: for-loop, recursion

I can calculate factorial using recursion or for loop as below?

Recursive factorial

```
int recursiveFactorial(int n){
    if(n<0)
        return;
    if(n==0 || n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*recursiveFactorial(n-1);
}
```

and using for loop

```
int forFacotrial(int n){
    if(n<0)
        return;
    if(n==0 || n==1)
        return 1;
    else{
       int fact=1;
       for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
       {
             fact=fact*i;
       }
       return fact;
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the both is it in terms of performance? What else difference does it have?

Comment: Yes. You are right . Difference is in terms of performance...

Comment: yeah that is fine. Is there difference in terms of performance? As I know there would be n calls to recursiveFactorial fuction. and the loop goes upto n times as well. so the complexity is O(n) for both right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695104/speed-performance-for-recursion-and-iteration-why-do-they-both-run-at-the-same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will pay a heavy penalty with the recursive version, because besides the overhead for the call, you will repeatedly compare the value of `n` against `<0`, `==0` and `==1`, which is unnecessary in the loop version.

A slightly more efficient recursive version could be:

```
int F(int n)
return n < 3 ? n : n * F(n-1)
```

called from

```
int G(int n)
return n < 2 ? 1 : F(n)
```

Comment: The recursive solution is also costly in terms of stack space, as it allocates room for every nested call. Here it is proportional to n. In general this is unacceptable. In this particular case, it is harmless given that the factorial overflows integers for n>=13. [And byt the way, tabulating the 14 values would be the best solution.]

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise loop is faster and also safer. When you call recursive methods always it execute as a method call. therefore it allocation memory on stack. If infinitely call a recursive method it may cause stack overflow exception. When you use a loop the memory allocation happens in heap there for its performance wise good and safer.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between **recursion** and **loop** :

-Loop **repeat it self** , but it has **just one phase** : ascending phase or the execution in the calling time (when the function it is called).

-Recursion **repeat it self** , but it  has **TWO phase** instead of one : ascending phase and descending phase or execution in the calling time and execution in the returning time.

What i mean by **Ascending phase**  and **Descending phase**  :

Ascending phase :

- Is that the code execution (Controller)will go to next instruction and the next instruction .....etc.. (-> **Execution in the calling time**)

Descending phase :

- Is that the code execution (Controller) will return back to the instruction that they did'nt executed due to the calling phase. (**Execution in the Returning time**)

Example:

```js
 void example(int n) {
     if(n>0){
      1.//Instruction during the calling time 
      2.//Instruction during the calling time
      3. example(n-1) 
      4. //Instruction executed when it will finish the Ascending phase  (Returning phase) 
      
     }
       }
       
       //Output expected  for n =3 : 3,2,1  printing is done at calling time
    
      /*      fun(3)
              /       \
              3        fun(2)
              /        \
              2        fun(1)
             /           \
             1           func(0)
             |                |
           calling pahse     - returning phase\
      */
       void func(int n){
       if(n>0){
        print(n)  //Instruction during the calling time 
        func(n-1)
                  // Intruction during the returning time (there is nothing so it                     will do nothing more when it will return back )
       }
       }
      //Output expected for n=3 : 1,2,3 printing is done at returning time
      /*      fun(3)
              /       \
              func(2)  -      3
              /        \
             func(1)    -     2
             /           \
             func(0)     -    1
             |
          - calling phase   returning phase  
      */
       void func(int n){
       if(n>0){
       func(n-1) //Instruction during the calling time
       print(n) //Instruction during the returning time 
       }
       
       }
```